# Spring data JPA delete query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to see if this is the right way to write delete query using spring JPA. I have a table with primary key of `id` and foreign key of `study_id`. I want to delete a row based on `study_id`. I wasn't able to just use `delete` method in JPA because `study_id` is not unique key. So I wrote new method:

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE STUDY_ID = :studyId", nativeQuery = true)
    int deleteByStudyId(@Param("studyId") long studyId);
```

I found this from https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-data-jpa-delete-query/#3_Delete_Operation_using_Custom_Query. However, I am not sure why @Transactional and `nativeQuery` is necessary in order to process it correctly. Without them, I get errors. I am also wondering if this is right way to delete from the table. This works, but I am very new to spring JPA.

Comment: Why you want to do in that way? If you are using Spring Data Jpa and your Daos/Repositories extends from `JpaRepository` or `CrudRepository`, there are methods like `delete(T entity)` or `deleteById(ID id)`you can use for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not sure why @Transactional and nativeQuery is necessary in order
> to process it correctly.

Without nativeQuery means you are using JPQL then you should use Entity name and column name in Entity not database table name or column

> I am also wondering if this is right way to delete from the table.

I think easier way is to use JPA method naming query this way

```
Long deleteByStudyId(long studyId);
```

Comment: Yes, using JPA deleteBy() is efficient and JPA repositories are bydefault transactional so you don't have to worry about transactional annoation anymore and also you don't have to write native query for this.